# what are the common used fast Edge Detection Algorithm using GPU shader(glsl, hlsl, not CUDA)?

Tags: algorithm, shader, fragment-shader, edge-detection, compute-shader

what's the fastest Edge Detection Algorithm using GPU shader(glsl, hlsl, not CUDA)?

1. just fragment-shader, just image-processing, no matter the image is colorful or gray
2. color buffer with normal buffer and depth buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple edge detector using convolution matrix (partial derivation by x):

```
-1 +1
```

and (partial derivation by y):

```
-1
+1
```

You can do this with standard pipeline no need for compute shaders:

1. **render rectangle covering screen/image/whatever**

   with input image as texture
2. **in fragment shader compute the edge (1st derivation)**

   so for each fragment fetch corresponding 2 (or 3 if done both derivations in one step) texels compute the resulting color and output it

both partial derivations are sometimes combined together one goes to one channel of color and the other to next one ...

In case you do this in 2D you can also use depth buffer to obtain 3D position and do also partial derivation in z axis ...

This approach is fast as GPU is rendering just single rectangle with very simple shaders

Comment: thanks, how about the result compared to the Sobel algorithm?
and is the Sobel algorithm fast in fragment shader? or is there better one which both consider speed and result?

Comment: @gpu Sobel edge detector is the same approach it just uses bigger convolution matrix (3x3) instead of (2x1 or 1x2) its like sliding average of 3 consequent rows or columns so its slightly slower (needs 3 times more texture fetches and few more math operations as it uses also more than just single weight) The result will be with less holes in it however sharp gradient changes will be smoothed slightly

Comment: thanks! so if want to draw the edge as an overlay on the original pic, the simple edge detector u mentioned above will be enough and best for this requirement, right?

Comment: yes you just threshold it and if the result is abs bigger than some value you render edge pixel with some color ... otherwise `discard;`

Comment: thanks, how to ditermine the "threshold value" for 1x1 filter or sobel filter?

Comment: Sobel: Quick but fails to detect weak edges, deals good in presence of noise

FuzzyLogic: Comparatively slow. Require tuning in presence of noise (not sure how much tedious)

Canny: Considered good so far due to non-maximal suppression and two thresholding which extracts most of the edges. Fails badly in presence of noise, need manual tuning of parameters.

how about the superiority and disadvantages of 1x1 filter?

and if want to draw the edge as an overlay on the original pic, which method is the most suitable?

Comment: @gpu There is no "general" approach in DIP/CV all depends on input image for noisy images is sometimes used approach that: 1. blur image 2. substract original - blured image 3. threshold the result. The idea is that blur will leak all objects edges (slightly enlarge objects) and by substracting getting the outlines... however note that such edges will be placed slightly offset for filled objects outwards and for hollow objects both outwards and inwards (producing doubled edges)...

Comment: thanks. this method need Multi-Pass while rendering, what algorithm is best when only One-Pass while rendering?

Comment: for camera images, is de-noisy nessesary to do before edge-detect? if so, then it's impossible to do edge-dectection in One-Pass, right?

Comment: @gpu you can blur and edge detect in single pass too its just 2 convolutions ... however its slower as you need to compute the same blurred pixels more than once.